# Bind complex object to mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-binding

I'm creating an mvc4 application and i have an issue.

I have a model class for example:

```
 public class ModelClass
{
   public ClassA a {get; set;}
   public ClassB b {get; set;}
   public ClassC c {get; set;}
   ...
}
```

Each of thease classes have their own properties, for example:

```
public class ClassA
{
   public String a1 {get; set;}
   public String a2 {get; set;}
   ...
}

 public class ClassB
{
   public String b1 {get; set;}
   public String b2 {get; set;}
   ...
}

...
```

I have a view like this:

```
<input type="text" name="a1" id="a1" />
<input type="text" name="a2" id="a1" />
<input type="text" name="b1" id="a1" />
<input type="text" name="b2" id="a1" />
...
```

How should my controller or view look so I can bind ModelClass to Controller?

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateSomething(ModelClass model)
    {
       //insert code here
    }
```

Or I have to do a custom model binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing you need to do in your controller. You simply need to name your inputs properly. Based on your structure. Your fields should look like:

```
<input type="text" name="a.a1" />
<input type="text" name="a.a2" />
<input type="text" name="b.b1" />
<input type="text" name="b.b2" />
```

It's preferable to just use the HTML helpers as they'll always generate the right names for you. For example:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.a.a1)
```

Answer (score -1):

There might be some neat solutions out there, but if things get too complicated, you can always fall back on `FormCollection`. Your code would then look something like this;

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateSomething(FormCollection collection)
{
    var model = new ModelClass();
    model.a = new ClassA();
    model.a.a1 = collection["a1"].ToString();
    model.a.a2 = collection["a2"].ToString();
    //....

    model.b = new ClassB();
    model.b.b1 = collection["b1"].ToString();
    model.b.b2 = collection["b2"].ToString();
    //...
}
```

In my opinion this is the most controllable solution, though it is not the most elegant. It nearly always works.

Comment: Do not use a `FormCollection`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt care to explain? At least I can learn something too then.

Comment: `FormCollection` is not strongly typed, so you have to keep your string indexes lined up with your class property names. If something changes on your class, you've now have to remember to update this code as well or your application breaks in often not obvious ways. The OPs problem has nothing to do with the choice of binding to a class instead of using a `FormCollection`, so your answer simply sidesteps the problem by introducing an even more brittle solution.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Makes sense. I'll remove the answer as soon as the OP has seen it. Thanks for the clarity.